# JOOMLA: How to retrieve values of all the fields with JInput but without jform[]

Tags: joomla, jinput, jform

As we know we can retrieve values of all the fields if they have names like `name="jform[something]"` and we can use the code:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = new JRegistry($jinput->get('jform', '', 'array'));
```

But is there some way to do the same if we have form with some name for example `<form name="myForm">` and fields with names like `name="something"` i.e. without `jform[]` ?

Thanks in advance

Joomla 3.5.1

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to retrieve post data array, you don't need to use JRegistry:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$data = $jinput->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

If you just need one parameter use the same function like this:

```
$something = $jinput->post->get("something");
```

*second and third parameters are *default_value* in case of no value found and *filter* (string, integer, ...).

Check [this page](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) for details. I would also suggest you to ask Joomla related questions on [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) to get better answers.

Comment: Thanks. For me it works only if I wrap it in `new JRegistry()`